# SimpleDB Manager

Tags: amazon-simpledb

anyone know a decent SimpleDB Manager Tool, web-based or Mac, preferably free? I am surprised AWS doesn't have one built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [SDB Tool](http://code.google.com/p/sdbtool/), a great Firefox plugin.  It's free and I've never had a problem.

Comment: Check this link for getting SDBTool to work with the latest versions of Firefox. http://code.google.com/p/sdbtool/issues/detail?id=31

Answer (score 11):

A free tool (Google Chrome plugin) is available at https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ddhigekdfabonefhiildaiccafacphgg?hc=search&hcp=main

Comment: +1 The chrome plugin is called SDBNavigator. It's really good and allowed me to cut the final tie with Firefox.

Comment: -1 I do not agree. One of the things you can do in simpleDB is store a list in a value. SDBNav doesn't give a proper UI for that type of data. In fact it flattens a list that should be inside of a value up to the top level values. I've tried several tools and SDB Explorer, which unfortunately is not free, seems best. I've also been building my own UI but it isn't to a place where I could share it.

Comment: Since v2.0.0 both missing (null) and multiple (array) values are supported by the interface

Comment: Would be nice if clicking a header to sort didn't overwrite your whole damn query.  How about making it just sort the current result set!?  Gotta wonder what these people were thinking.  So be sure to have your query in your clipboard at all times if you don't want to lose your work.  I am going to be moving away from SimpleDB soon, as the tools surrounding it seems anything but simple.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately there aren't any really well done SimpleDB Managers.  I've used [Scratchpad](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1137), [SDB Explorer](http://www.sdbexplorer.com/), and the [SdbNavigator chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sdbnavigator/ddhigekdfabonefhiildaiccafacphgg).  All have limitations.  Don't waste your time on Scratchpad or your money on SDB Explorer - SdbNavigator is free and works better.

Personally I use SdbNavigator to run ad-hoc queries and small deletes.  For most everything else I write simple Python scripts using [Boto](https://github.com/boto/boto).

I haven't found anything that does multi-value attribute fields so it is best to just script it for now.

If you've got an IPad, I recommend [CloudBase](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloudbase/id548658505?mt=8) for managing SimpleDB and running queries.  It's nice because you can save queries which reduces unnecessary typing.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon makes this tool available as a sample.  [Javascript Scratchpad for Amazon SimpleDB](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1137)

Comment: No offence, but this tool is very poor/bare. Also it doesn't allow for changing region from default `us-east-1` :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use **SDB Explorer**. SDB Explorer provides an industry-leading and intuitive Graphical User Interface (GUI) to explore Amazon SimpleDB service in a thorough manner, and in a very efficient and user friendly way.

You can download and use SDB Explorer free for 30 days. The free version will stop working after 30 days if it isn't activated with a paid license key. It has many features like..

1. CSV Export/Import.
2. Experience fast, Multiple and parallel operartions.
3. Quick Search on Amazon SimpleDB Domain.
4. In-place cell editing.
5. Upload My-SQL data to Amazon SimpleDB.
6. AWS IAM interface to manage users, groups, polices and credentials for Amazon SimpleDB service.
7. Easy Listing of Domains from all Region End Points supported by Amazon SimpleDB.
8. Execute Queries like in any standard Database Query Tool.
9. Support for MAC/Linux/Windows platform.
10. On-line Help, Documentation, Demos, Screen shots, Discussion forums and Product Support.

http://www.sdbexplorer.com/

Comment: The SDB Explorer tool no longer exists.

Answer (score 1):

If for some reason the SDBNavigator Crome Plugin mentioned in another answer is not applicable for you, the tool RazorSQL also supports SimpleDB. It is not free though, and a Java Application.

Answer (score 1):

The tool that ended up working best for me was the SimpleDB management as part of the aws sdk for eclipse.

Even if you're not using eclipse for development, it's a simple install in order to just use it for SimpleDb management. Instructions:

- eclipse install [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup_prereqs.html)
- aws toolkit install [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/GettingStartedGuide/tke_setup_install.html).

When choosing the components in the eclipse "available software" dialog, just pick these 2:

- AWS Toolkit for Eclipse Core
- Amazon SimpleDB Management

Once installed, show the AWS Explorer view (Window->Show View->Other and type 'aws'). It'll prompt you for your aws credentials. In the AWS Explorer view, you'll see Amazon SimpleDB in the tree.

This tool let's you:

- Choose a region
- Create/delete domains
- Query the domain
- Edit items
- Export data to .csv
- View domain metadata, like item count and total size